# SSL certificate multiple domain. Reuse certificate

Tags: ssl, https, dns

Mi question is really simple:

I have one server that owns multiple domains inside. Recently I bought a SSL certificate for one of them.

Is there any possibility to reuse that one certificate?

In other words, is SSL certificate related to the domain, or the hosting machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each certificate can be used just by one domain, despite, you can use it for all your subdomains.

https://ssl.comodo.com/wildcard-ssl-certificates.php

Answer (score 0):

If you purchased a wildcarded certificate that is valid for *.*yourdomain.com*, you can reuse it for other subdomains.